# Input Fields Are Too Wide

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am designing a responsive web page which contains a form.
But all the input elements are getting out of the form from left and right.
Can anyone tell me, What is the reason behind this.?

**My Demo Code ...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temp Pages for Testing </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css">        
    <style>
        .custFrmOnlyBkCol { background-color: lightgray;    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="#" class="custFrmOnlyBkCol">
                <!--        In Css :  .custFrmOnlyBkCol { background-color: lightgray;    }     -->
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-3 text-right">Id</label>
                    <div>
                        <p>101</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-3 text-right" for="">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-9">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-3 text-right" for="">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-9">
                </div>
                <input class="form-control offset-md-3 col-md-6 btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please could you also share the code in `wastte.css` because that is likely to be where the width of your `input` elements are set.

Comment: If you want to keep the Bootstrap styles for the `form-control` inputs, but give them the widths you want, add the desired width to your own styles. Otherwise, you can remove the Bootstrap classes from the inputs. (Bootstrap has things like `.form-control {display:block;}` which interfere with your design here.)

Comment: Dont set width:100% if there are non zero margins for them.

Comment: no such file is there, that was linked by mistake,thanks to you for making me correct.

Comment: it is working fine for me, please check sample code - https://codepen.io/piyushjn/pen/eqPBdg

Comment: @piyushjain Any particular reason for making a lot of changes and then not mentioning those?

Answer (score 0):

Set the widths of the input

```
input {
width: x%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put input tags inside a div with row class like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temp Pages for Testing </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css">        
    <style>
        .custFrmOnlyBkCol { background-color: lightgray;    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="#" class="custFrmOnlyBkCol">
                <!--        In Css :  .custFrmOnlyBkCol { background-color: lightgray;    }     -->

               <div class="row col-md-10">

                    <label for="" class="col-md-3 text-right">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-9">

               </div>
               <div class="row col-md-10">

                    <label for="" class="col-md-3 text-right">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-9">

               </div>

                <input class="form-control offset-md-3 col-md-6 btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```